# PresentationFramework.ni.dll causes CPU freezinig

Tags: .net, dll, compilation, freeze

I wrote an app under .NET 3.5 on the my computer No.1. It was run prefectly.
When I moved app to the other computer, it is started huge CPU freeze while an app is run.

I've traced it, and found that source of the trouble is *PresentationFramework.ni.dll*. It loads CPU even when app is do nothing. 
Then I've compiled app under .NET version 4.0. And problem is gone. So I explained, that I've found source of problem correct.

[image]

But I need an app compiled exactly under .NET version 3.5. So, how can I do this without CPU freezing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, nobody answered, that's why I post my temporary solution. That is, use another version of .NET.